# What sets nb_bool in CPython?

Tags: cpython, python-internals

By default, `nb_bool` slot on the Python type object should not exist. Otherwise, if the default `slot_nb_bool` exists, upon invocation, it will cause infinite recursion when `__len__` is defined.

If so, what sets `nb_bool` in the following scenario?

```
class A:
  pass
A.__bool__ = lambda x: 0
assert not A()
```

Type object has no descriptor set for `__bool__`, and metaclass `__setattr__` does not seem to be handling it according to CPython source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type`'s  `tp_setattro` slot (`__setattr__`) does handle it.

Upon setting an attribute on a class, [`type_setattro`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3506) is called.

It [checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3550) if the attribute is a dunder method. If it is, it updates the appropriate slot.